# Tracking network activity for user login/logout/session timeout/session expired

Tags: networking, scripting, timeout, session

Porting from StackOverflow (35741797), since it might be a bit more relevant here as it is related to network.

We have a situation on our side where we are trying to trace the login/logout/session expiration/timeout for particular users. To explain in brief, we have certain customers who are complaining that while accessing our website, they are experiencing frequent session expiration and timeouts. We have the standard timeout setting but only few users accessing a particular website are complaining about it.

Network team believes that it might be the network (wireless network, ethernet. etc or may be even using multiple tabs) on the client side that is causing this, since we are not able to replicate it in-house. Is there is an easy way we can trace their network traffic to our website and see exact what happens when they get this timeout errors? Unfortunately, we cannot install network monitor or such tools on their end (client side) and I tried something like this before :-

```
netsh trace start capture=yes persistent=yes
netsh trace stop
```

But it is not very easy to read the NetTrace with this method. We do not believe that it is an issue with our site since other users (outside our network) can access it without any issue but only those from a particular location are experiencing this. Is there any easy functionality in VB-Script/Batch/Python to generate a kind of detailed and human readable/understandable log to trace the root cause of these frequent timeouts?

Server: Windows 7 Browser: Chrome, Firefox, IE (all upgraded to the latest version)

Comment: These are external clients. You can't replicate the problem in house. I'm assuming that means that you can't replicate the problem from the same network that the web server is on. You ought to be testing this from a different network to truly replicate the same conditions that a user has. I'm guessing that a firewall idle timer is at work here.

Comment: Can you suggest a methodology to easily check this? The challenges we have - 1. We cannot install any new softwares or edit registry or similar on the client side. 2. It would be difficult to access to their network + they have SSO so the options are again limited. I check the What's up Gold, forums and they do some network traffic monitoring but not sure how well they monitor the packets and can give the history of all the traffic when the users access a particular site. So in brief, I am looking for ideas that can be easy implemented then I can develop a solution around it.